# Edit type of field in registration form woocommerce

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

I use the following code [to add custom fields in user registration on the "My Account" page](https://support.woothemes.com/hc/en-us/articles/203182373-How-to-add-custom-fields-in-user-registration-on-the-My-Account-page)  using woocommerce,it worked succesfully, but now i want to change the type of one fields be displayed as a `select` to display only 3 state:
- Paris,
- London
- Algiers
 So how can I edit this code:

```
<p class="form-row form-row-last">
    <label for="reg_billing_state"><?php _e( 'State', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_state" id="reg_billing_state" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_state'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_state'] ); ?>" />

    </p>
```

I have tried this but it doesn't work!

```
<p class="form-row form-row-last">
    <label for="reg_billing_state"><?php _e( 'Commune', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <input  list="states" class="input-text" name="billing_state" id="reg_billing_state" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_state'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_state'] ); ?>" />
    <datalist id="states">
    <option value="Paris">
    <option value="London">
    <option value="Algiers">
  </datalist> 
    </p>
```

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: Thanks for your note, done!

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**
The solution I found for now is the following:

```
<p class="form-row form-row-last">
    <label for="reg_billing_state"><?php _e( 'Commune', 'woocommerce' ); ?> <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <select id="reg_billing_state" class="input-text" name="billing_state">
        <option value="Alger">Alger</option>
        <option value="Zeralda">Zeralda</option>
        <option value="Beni Messous">Beni Messous</option>
    </select>
</p>
```